# Принцип MVVM в WPF

Tags: mvvm, view, binding, model, viewmodel

Простите если задаю глупый вопрос, но никах не могу понять.
View -> ViewModel -> Model или View <-> ViewModel -> Model или еще как то?
Так какой принцип отношений между View, ViewModel и Model.

Comment: Model - данные, то есть некий слой, который работает с базой, с сайтом, с устройством, портом, простым текстовым файлом и т.д. Сам слой должен быть самостоятельным, не знать про VM и V слои. View - это чисто UI, то есть стили, контролы, цвет, шрифт и т.д.. Слой должен быть также максимально самодостаточном, не знать про M и VM. Остается ViewModel - связующий слой, который опрашивает Model, на его основе делает нужные свойства для привязки, обрабатывает команды. Он не должен знать что-либо про V! Собственно, суть MVVM в том, чтоб отделить данные и UI, сделав их самодостаточными.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.